# error "activity class does not exist" when launching android app with adb shell am start

Tags: android, air, adb

After `adb install`-ing my app, I can verify that it's there with `adb shell pm list packages AppName`:

> package:air.com.client.AppName

So I *know* it's there, but when I try to launch it with `adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n air.com.client/.AppName`, I get this error:

> Starting: Intent { cmp=air.com.client/.AppName}
>
> Error type 3
>
> Error: Activity class {air.com.client/air.com.client.AppName} does not exist.

If it matters, this is, as you may have noticed, an AIR app that's been packaged as an Android app. Any ideas? Did I miss something somewhere? When I use `aapt dump xmltree` I can see that my .apk includes an `android.intent.action.MAIN` entry in the intent-filter node, for what it's worth.

And finally, for sanity's sake, using the same command template I can launch the settings app with no problems:

```
adb shell am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n com.android.settings/.Settings
```

Comment: There is no `air.com.client` class. The class name is `air.com.client.AppName`.

Comment: you're gonna have to spell it out for me - what should the command be?

Comment: related q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28388523/cannot-get-this-adb-shell-am-start-line-to-work

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Managed to figure it out - I left a prompt open with `adb logcat`, then launched my app on the device - out of this corresponding log entry:

> I/ActivityManager( 2115): START u0 {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=air.com.client.AppName/.AppEntry} from pid 2453

I put together a new command line:

```
adb shell start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER -n air.com.client.AppName/.AppEntry
```

... which does exactly what I wanted. I'll be honest, I don't understand exactly *why* it works, but that's good enough for now.

Comment: I think you should add between 'shell' and 'start', am. Because you are using the activity manager

Answer (score 25):

Watch out for `applicationIdSuffix`!!

When using `applicationIdSuffix` in *build.gradle* the suffix only applies to your application id, not to the actual package structure in the generated .apk, meaning that referencing your activity the short way (`.MainActivity`, instead of using its fully qualified name) will add the application id suffix to the path of the activity too and hence AS will fail to locate it. E.g.:

My application's package name is `my.application.package`, and I have this in my app module's *build.gradle*:

```
buildTypes {
           
    someBuildType {
        [...]
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
    }
}
```

When trying to execute, let's say `MainActivity` (which is located in the root package) from the command line:

```
$ adb shell am start -n my.application.package.dev/.MainActivity
```

actually resolves to

```
$ adb shell am start -n my.application.package.dev/my.application.package.dev.MainActivity
```

But `MainActivity` is actually located in `my.application.package.MainActivity`, not in `my.application.package.dev.MainActivity`, because `applicationIdSuffix` changes only the application id, not the actual package structure, so it will fail to locate it.

Therefore, you should use the activity's fully qualified name:

```
$ adb shell am start -n my.application.package.dev/my.application.package.MainActivity
```

Answer (score 4):

At lease for me the issue was solved once I entered a full path to the main activity in the application manifest file.

Instead of:

```
<activity android:name=".MyMainActivity"/>
```

Use:

```
<activity android:name="com.fullPathToActivityPackage.MyMainActivity"/>
```

and then use the regular:

```
adb shell am start -n com.myAppPackage/com.fullPathToActivityPackage.MyMainActivity
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is for writing only the activity name without it's package

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n air.com.client/.AppName
```

Is wrong,

First, You should enter the activity name (not the AppName), and second you can't enter the activity name without the package name .AppName alone wouldn't work. you should enter air.com.client.AppName even if the activity is in the exact same package as the application package.

This would probably work

```
am start -a android.intent.action.MAIN -n air.com.client.AppName/air.com.client.ActivityName
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a new project by copying another existing, and got this problem. None of the answers above helped as all seemed to be correct. And what eventually resolved the issue in my case was just a restart of the Andriod Studio.

Comment: Does not resolve my problem. Why is the package name duplicated in the shell command? This is the reason the activity can not be found.

Answer (score 1):

Check that in your field of Application in your device not has the apk with the same name. The new devices has paper bin and there is the problem.

Comment: Thanks, for me this helped.  My uninstalled the app from my emulator and re-launched it

Answer (score 0):

For AIR application there is specific prefix and postifx.
This works for me, application package is `cz.jara`

```
adb shell am start -n air.cz.jara/air.cz.jara.AppEntry
```

Note that sometimes there is .DEBUG appended to the package name.